# calculate median value of a function

Tags: functions, probability-distributions, median

need help on this one please ! [I already tried to calculate with F(x) = 0.5 but doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjeVZ.jpg)

Comment: Include your attempt at the solution in your question.  We can help you spot your mistake, if you've made one.

Comment: Can't upload an other file, doesn't work --" I calculate for example for the first equation : integral of 0.01x² between -4 and b (median), and the result is egal to 0.5 and I can calculate b.

Comment: You need to calculate the CDF across the entire range of the distribution, not just between -4 and -3.

Comment: Ok and how can I do that ? because it's not the same equation for all the same number

Comment: I've posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the median, you need to find the value of $x$ that satisfies the equation $F_x(x) = 0.5$.

In order to find $F_x(x)$, we must perform the following calculations.

For the range $-4 \lt x \lt -3$, $\int_{-4}^x 0.01u^2du$

For the range $-3 \lt x \lt -2$, $\int_{-4}^{-3} 0.01x^2dx$

For the range $-2 \lt x \lt -1$, $\int_{-4}^{-3} 0.01x^2dx + \int_{-2}^x(0.2u+0.5)du$

For the range $-1 \lt x \lt 2$, $\int_{-4}^{-3} 0.01x^2dx + \int_{-2}^{-1}(0.2x+0.5)dx$

For the range $2 \lt x \lt 3$, $\int_{-4}^{-3} 0.01x^2dx + \int_{-2}^{-1}(0.2x+0.5)dx +\int_{2}^x0.1udu$

For the range $3 \lt x \lt 7$, $\int_{-4}^{-3} 0.01x^2dx + \int_{-2}^{-1}(0.2x+0.5)dx +\int_{2}^30.1u du + \int_{3}^ucx^4du$

From this you'll have your $F_x(x)$.  For each range, find the $x$ which satisfies $F_x(x) = 0.5$, and if $x$ lies in your permitted range, then there you have it!

Comment: can i ask you why there are more ranges ? Because between -3 and -2 the function is 0 no ?  and the same for -1 to 2, I don't get it I'm sorry... And what the u for ?

Comment: The *u* is just a dummy variable so that we can integrate with an upper limit of *x*.  The extra ranges where the pdf solves to 0 are necessary as we are considering a CDF.  Hence, across these ranges, because there are no probabilities, the cumulative probability stays the same, which is why the CDF in these ranges are constant.  Solve the integrals, then plot the CDF, and it will make much more sense.

Comment: ok thank you for your answer ! Trying it now and I'll see :)

Comment: don't have the right answer with all of that --" i just don't get it :$

Comment: I did it ! Thank you so much for your help ! I don't know what I would have done without it ! Thank you !